# get json root intger data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var data={
    "394": {
        "category": "ball",
        "imgSrc": "sd",
        "score": 0
    },
    "395": {
        "category": "ball",
        "imgSrc": "",
        "score": 1
    }
};
```

I want to print 394 and 395. Please help me. Also please how can I order score wise? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this fiddle: (from your other deleted question)

http://jsfiddle.net/CS52y/

Step One: convert and flatten this particular object structure:

```
function parseThisObjectToArray(oInput) {
    var aOutput = [];
    for(var prop in oInput) {
        var o = {};
        // flatten this specific object structure
        o.id = prop;
        o.category= oInput[prop].category;
        o.imgSrc = oInput[prop].imgSrc;
        o.score = oInput[prop].score;
        // add flattened object to output
        aOutput[aOutput.length] = o;
    }
    return aOutput;
}
```

Step Two: Sort the new flattened data.

```
function sortThisArrayOfObjectsBySubProperty(aInput) {
    aInput.sort(function(a,b) { return parseInt(a.score) - parseInt(b.score) } );
    return aInput;
}
```

Like this:

```
// flatten data
data = parseThisObjectToArray(data);
// sort this data
data = sortThisArrayOfObjectsBySubProperty(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do the trick...

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

If you want to reference the data within those objects, you can do it like this...

```
for (var key in data) {
    console.log(data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
for(var key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key); // 394 , 395
    }
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2A3WL/)**

Comment: You can use `console.log(data[key].score);` instead of `console.log(key);` Check updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2A3WL/1/